# How to disconnect phone call by button?

Tags: android

how to disconnect phone call by button.I am using following code:

```
try {
        // Java reflection to gain access to TelephonyManager's
        // ITelephony getter
        Log.v(TAG, "Get getTeleService...");
        Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m
                .invoke(tm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "FATAL ERROR: could not connect to telephony subsystem");
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception object: " + e);
```

Answer (score 1):

For disconnecting a call programmatically you must add `ITelephony.AIDL` file in your project. If you have added it, then your package name must be `com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.AIDL`: for more information see [Blocking Incoming call](http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html). Download the AIDL file from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.java).

To disconnect a call use `endCall();` method of `ITelephony`

Comment: I want to create my own dialer which will  have own widgets for calling and diconnecting.